# Iphone/Ipad : What is the fastest way to draw an irregular polygon in a rectangle?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have to draw the following shape in a rectangle.  What is the best way to do it?  The blue areas are the background color.  The black is a border and the red is the interior color.  I want to paint the black and red only.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It totally depends on how you would use the shape; whether they will move, how many of them will be displayed, whether they will be scaled while being displayed, etc.

In general, OpenGL ES is considered to be the fastest way of drawing on iOS devices. However, if you have only a small number of those shape (say, <10~100?) and the other part of the application does not have a lot of fast animations Quart 2D is usually enough in terms of drawing, in order to, say, achieve a 30/60Hz drawing rate.

How you use Quartz2D still matters a lot. If you need to redraw the shapes frequently, you would need to draw the shape on CALayers, and rather than redrawing the shapes, you should move and transform the layers.

Comparing drawing as a bitmap and a vector shape, I believe both would work fine for this kind of shape (especially because you would *not* redraw the shape so often, but only work with the layer on which the image already is drawn). But if your shapes are scaled frequently, you would consider vector images for the quality of the image.

To summarize, learn (if you don't already know) how to draw into a graphics context first (see *Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS*). You should be able to draw a simple vector shape or a bitmap image by overriding `drawRect` or similar methods inside a UIView object. Then if you need to animate those shapes, learn how to create a CALayer and draw on the layer (see *Core Animation Programming Guide*). Finally, if you need to create many duplicates of the shape on the screen, learn how to use CGLayer to replicate an image (see *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*).

Comment: If the background is not a constant color, is there some way to read the current background and then draw the shape over that particular rectangle?  I need to do this very frequently, so performance is paramount.  Thanks for the answer, it gives me the direction I need to go in.

Comment: I wish Apple's docs would outline the learning curve in such a clear, linear fashion.  Thx!